# Jquery fails to execute controller action and refresh partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with a modal window that you can drag an image to for upload. Upon clicking save button on the modal window, I post the image to my controller's UploadImage action, hide the modal, then make another ajax call to a get action to reload a PartialView that contains a list of images uploaded.

My image uploads fine, but the Partial action is never hit.

I don't have a lot of experience with Jquery so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is the relevant part of my view:

```
    <div id="viewSavedContentAreaDiv">
        @Html.Action("PartImagesPartial", "Part", new { PartID = Model.ID }) 
    </div>
```

This is the relevant part of my controller:

```
    public ActionResult PartImagesPartial(int PartID)
    {
        IEnumerable<PartImageViewModel> images = _map.GetPartImages(PartID);

        return PartialView("PartImagesPartial", images);
    }
```

This is the relevant Jquery in my js file:

```
$("#btnDroppedSave").click(function () {

var imgSource = $("#drop").find("img").attr("src");

if (imgSource == undefined)
    $("#validateDroppedImage").show();

if (imgSource != undefined) {
    var partId = $('#ID').val();
    var formData = new FormData();
    var totalFiles = 1;
    var dropedFile = newFile;
    formData.append("FileUpload", dropedFile);
    formData.append("PartID", partId)

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Part/UploadImage',
        data: formData,
        dataType: "html",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
     });

    $('#part-image-modal').modal('hide');

    //this should refresh PartImagesPartial
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Part/PartImagesPartial",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        contentType: false,
        data: { PartID: (partId) },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#viewSavedContentAreaDiv").empty().append(result);
        }
    });        
}
});
```

The PartImagesPartial action is never hit after the button click, but the file does upload. If I manually refresh the containing view, the partial shows the list of images including the new image. Any ideas what I'm screwing up here?

Comment: Keep in mind that the first "a" in "ajax" stands for "asynchronous".  You want to wait for the first ajax to return before you start doing the rest of the stuff.  Put it in the `.success` method. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You nailed it, thanks for the reminder! I didn't realize that the first ajax might not have returned yet. With the partial ajax inside the success method everything works great. Thank you.

If you post this as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has the second ajax call happening before the first ajax call returns which causes the issue.  If you move both your modal hide and the second call into the `.success` method of the first ajax then it should fix it.  I would probably wrap the second ajax call in a separate function and have that called rather than nesting the ajax call itself.  Something like this:

```
//... function stuff up here
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '/Part/UploadImage',
       data: formData,
       dataType: "html",
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function() {
           RefreshPartial();
       },
       complete: function(){
           $('#part-image-modal').modal('hide');
       }
    });

}//--- end previous function here

function RefreshPartial(){
   //this should refresh PartImagesPartial
   $.ajax({
       url: "/Part/PartImagesPartial",
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "html",
       contentType: false,
       data: { PartID: (partId) },
       success: function (result) {
           $("#viewSavedContentAreaDiv").empty().append(result);
       }
   }); 
}
```

You can play around a bit with when you close the modal, see what looks best.  Putting it in the `complete` means it will happen at the very end which may or may not be what you want.

Special side note:
The new jQuery specs have `success`, `error`, and `complete` as depreciated and replaced with more of a stringing notation using `.done(...)`, `.fail(...)`, and `.always(...)`.  More info on that here:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/